# JQuery Validator Checkbox onClick update error message inconsistent behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've created a pretty standard checkbox JQuery Validation example: https://jsfiddle.net/rbL62zm8/1/

For clarity, `console.log` statements have been omitted from code in this question.

The validation `rules` require a Number or String type be selected. If a Number is selected, a numeric type must also be selected (Int, Float or Double).

```
var validationRules = {
    debug: true,
    rules: {
      'type': {
        // Number or String
        required: true,
      },
      'numeric': {
        // Int, Float or Double.
        required: '#typeNumber:checked'
      }
    },
    messages: {
      'type': {
        required: 'A data type is required.'
      },
      'numeric': {
        required: 'A numeric data type is required.'
      }
    },
    onclick: function(element) {
      $(element).valid();
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $("#validationMsg").html("The form is valid.");
      return false;
    },
    errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
      $("#validationMsg").html(label);
    },
  }
```

The corresponding HTML form:

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method='post' action=''>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" class="type-group" id="typeNumber" value="Number">
  <label for="typeNumber">Number</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" class="type-group" id="typeString" value="String" checked>
  <label for="typeString">String</label>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="numeric" class="numeric-group" id="numericInt" value="Int">
  <label for="numericInt">Int</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="numeric" class="numeric-group" id="numericFloat" value="Float">
  <label for="numericFloat">Float</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="numeric" class="numeric-group" id="numericDouble" value="Double">
  <label for="numericDouble">Double</label>
  <br />
  <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
  <input type='reset' name='Reset' value='Reset' />
</form>

<div id="validationMsg"></div>
```

The form's default state ensures the String checkbox is ticked:

[image]

I've added an `onclick` implementation in an attempt to validate the form whenever a checkbox is ticked or unticked.

**Use Case #1**

- Run the JSFiddle.
- Untick the String checkbox.

Outcome: An error message is displayed, which is correct.

**Use Case #2**

- Run the JSFiddle.
- Untick the String checkbox.
- Tick the String checkbox.

Outcome: An error message is displayed **and remains visible**. This seems inconsistent since the action that displayed the error message (un-ticking the checkbox) is reversed, yet the error message is not updated.

**Question:**
How can I validate **all** checkboxes whenever their state changes?

---

### Update

I implemented the `invalidHandler` in the [validation configuration object](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) by adding:

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
      var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
      console.log('Number of invalids: %s', errors);
    },
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xz1a43fm/

The `invalidHandler` function is only called when the form's in an invalid state. Therefore ticking the String checkbox takes the form into a valid state and `invalidHandler` is not called.

`submitHandler` is the closest thing to the counterpart of `invalidHandler` I can find - however this is called only `onSubmit` and not `onClick`.

---

### Final Solution

I had three requirements:

1. **Realtime Validation:** Validate checkboxes as the user's interacting with the form, not only at submission.
2. **Two-way Dependency:** Validate **two-way** dependencies. I.e. if `Number` is ticked, `Float`, `Int` or `Double` MUST be ticked, but also, if `Float`, `Int` or `Double` are ticked, `Number` MUST be ticked.
3. **Don't Hack:** Don't re-write built-in rules in a large custom validation method.

**Realtime validation:** Implementing a custom `onclick` function is common, however I was missing two crucial details:

1. Validating the entire form, rather than a single element. By calling `valid()` on the entire form, all inter-dependencies between checkbox groups could be assessed.
2. Checking for a valid state and clearing the error message manually if required (as suggested by @ZirboFilip).

The final `onclick` handler:

```
onclick: function(element) {
          // Validate the entire form.
          var valid = $('#mainForm').valid();
          // Clear error message manually if appropriate.
          if (valid) {
            $("#validationMsg").html('');
          }
    }
```

**Two-way Dependencies:**
The required attribute is great for one-way dependency, but it isn't right for checkbox group dependencies. A reasonable rule may be:

```
     'type': {
        required: true,
      },
      'numeric': {
        required: '#typeNumber:checked',
      }
```

However this only states that a numeric type is required if ANY type (Number or String) is checked. Consequently the following is valid:

[image]

...this is not what I wanted. I added a custom validation method:

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDependencies", function(value, element) {
    // return true if field is ok or should be ignored.
    var intChecked = $('#numericInt').prop('checked');
    var floatChecked = $('#numericFloat').prop('checked');
    var doubleChecked = $('#numericDouble').prop('checked');
    var numberChecked = $('#typeNumber').prop('checked');
    var stringChecked = $('#typeString').prop('checked');
    var numericTypeChecked = intChecked || floatChecked || doubleChecked;

    if (!numberChecked && stringChecked) {
      return !numericTypeChecked;
    }
    // Fall-back on built in rules for everything else.
    return true;
  });
```

I'll discuss this in more detail below while addressing my third requirement.

**Don't Hack:** I had only one additional requirement not covered by the built-in rules and dependencies, i.e. that String is not a valid type with when a Int, Float or Double is chosen.  I coded this in a custom rule (code above). Relevant code repeated below:

```
if (!numberChecked && stringChecked) {
      return !numericTypeChecked;
}
// Fall-back on built in rules for everything else.
return true;
```

However, after this check, I return `true`. While it was tempting to code other combinations in the same rule, by returning `true`, I continue to use the `required` rules, namely:

```
'numeric': {
        required: '#typeNumber:checked',
 }
```

Final JSFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/bmg2dcha/1/

Comment: Can there be both "Number" and "String" checked when submit or only 1 of them?

Comment: Both should be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
if($(element).valid()){
    ("#validationMsg").html("");
}
```

inside `onclick: function(element) { ... }` and it should be fine.